# Change to fixed on click

Tags: javascript

I have a bit of javascript. I want to achieve that when you click on the menuBtn class that it changes 'nav' to fixed fixed.

```
 // menu animation
$(window).load(function() {

    $('.menuBtn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        (this.classList.contains('is-active') === true) ? this.classList.remove('is-active'): this.classList.add('is-active');
        $('nav').slideToggle();
    });

});



$('.menuBtn').click(function() {
//nav position fixed// 

});
```

Comment: `'nav' to fixed fixed.` you mean position fixed?

Comment: Can you provide some more markup? What are you wanting to stay fixed?

Comment: We're going to need more information.

Comment: Yes position fixed

Comment: FYI: jQuery has `$(this).toggleClass('is-active')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.menuBtn').click(function() {
     $('.nav').css('position','fixed');
});
```

Not quite sure if nav is an ID or a class. # or . the code should look like this.